# What ANOVA should be used for paired data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, paired-data

Suppose I'm measuring bone densities from patients and normal persons. And for each person, I'm measuring twice, once without weight, and once with weight. So, what model should I use to estimate bone densities under each condition (patients without weight for example), and also compare the difference.

I thought of anova, but that kinda neglect the fact the data is paired (with/without weight for each person). But if I use the difference of paired data, I'm able to analyze the effect of such difference between patients and normal persons. But not necessarily the specific density estimation for each condition.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "once without weight, and once with weight"? What "weight"? This remains unanswered probably because nobody understands.

Answer (score 0):

There is repeated measures ANOVA, but it makes assumptions that are usually unrealistic.  I suggest a multilevel model.